# While True loop in python does not stop even when condition true is not met

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This is a simple rock, paper or scissors game. Whenever any of the players get a score of 3, the loop should break and print "game over". I'm a beginner but i cannot understand why the while True loop keeps running even when either score1 or score2 are >3.

```
print("---Rock  paper  or scissors ✂---")
print("")
print("Choose your move; R, P or S")

score1=0
score2=0
while True:
  player_1 = input ("Player 1 move? ")
  player_2 = input ("Player 2 move? ")
  if score1 <3 or score2 <3:
    if player_1 == player_2:
      print("Even round")
      continue
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "R":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "S":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "P":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "S":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "R":
      print("Player 2 won!")
      score2 += 1
      print(score2)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "P":
      print("Player 2 won!")
      score2 += 1
      print(score2)
      continue
  else:
    print("Game over")
    break
  
print ("Player 1 score was =", score1)
print ("Player 2 score was =", score2)
```

I ran out of solutions.

Comment: The condition `if score1 <3 or score2 <3:` should be `if score1 <3 and score2 <3:` (Also the `continue` statements are unnecessary)

Comment: It'd be cleaner to rewrite that as a guard statement: `if score1 >= 3 or score2 >= 3: break`. Or, even better, use it as the `while` condition: `while score1 < 3 and score2 < 3: ...` followed by `print("Game over")`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Beside the point, but a bunch of the win conditions are wrong. For example, scissors cut paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few issues with this code:

1. The first is the condition, `score1 <3 or score2 <3`. If you want the code to stop once any of the players reaches 3, you should change the `or` to `and`. Having an `or` means that either of them is true, then executes the code, so even when let's say score1 has been updated to 3 the loop continues.
2. You should switch your input after the conditioning, to make sure that you do not take input despite when your exit criteria are reached.

And one bonus; Instead of having an infinite loop and continues `while True:` you can use condition the while itself: `while score1 < 3 and score2 < 3:`

Also, if player1 is R and player2 is P; Shouldn't the player2 win?

One modified version would be:

```py
print("---Rock  paper  or scissors ✂---")
print("")
print("Choose your move; R, P or S")

score1=0
score2=0
while score1 < 3 and score2 < 3:
    print(f"Current scores: {score1} - {score2}")
    player_1 = input ("Player 1 move? ")
    player_2 = input ("Player 2 move? ")
    if player_1 == player_2:
        print("Even round")
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "R":
        print ("Player 1 won!")
        score1 += 1
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "S":
        print ("Player 1 won!")
        score1 += 1
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "P":
        print ("Player 2 won!")
        score2 += 1
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "S":
        print ("Player 1 won!")
        score1 += 1
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "R":
        print("Player 2 won!")
        score2 += 1
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "P":
        print("Player 2 won!")
        score2 += 1

print("Game over")
  
print ("Player 1 score was =", score1)
print ("Player 2 score was =", score2)
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam, you're just an amazing human being! You saved my a$$ :)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this issue because your if condition checks whether score 1 is less than 3 OR if score 2 is less than 3.  If player one has a score of 3 and player 2 has a score of 0, 1, or 2, your if condition is still true due to the OR.  Change this condition to an AND so that both scores must be less than 3 for the game to continue.  When 1 of the players reaches a score of 3, the IF statement evaluates to false and your loop exits.

Also you may want to put your input statements inside the if scores are less than 3 statement.  This way when a winner is found, you don't ask for the moves again before declaring a winner.

Here is what I would recommend:

```
print("---Rock  paper  or scissors ✂---")
print("")
print("Choose your move; R, P or S")

score1=0
score2=0
while True:

  if score1 < 3 and score2 < 3:
    player_1 = input ("Player 1 move? ")
    player_2 = input ("Player 2 move? ")
    if player_1 == player_2:
      print("Even round")
      continue
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "R":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "P" and player_2 == "S":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "P":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "R" and player_2 == "S":
      print ("Player 1 won!")
      score1 += 1
      print(score1)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "R":
      print("Player 2 won!")
      score2 += 1
      print(score2)
      continue
    elif player_1 == "S" and player_2 == "P":
      print("Player 2 won!")
      score2 += 1
      print(score2)
      continue
  else:
    print("Game over")
    break
  
print ("Player 1 score was =", score1)
print ("Player 2 score was =", score2)
```